# Optimal Magic Levels

Tags: cookie-clicker

With the Grimoire mini game that is tied to the Wizard tower, there are several spells that can be cast. Each of these spells have a cost that use your magic. This cost is a % of your maximum magic plus a flat rate.

According to the Cookie Clicker wiki, there are optimal max magic amounts for the shortest time to being able to cast the spell again.

How do I interpret this though? Does getting higher magic max make it take longer? Does higher magic max just give diminishing returns? Does a magic max that is optimal have a large difference compared to having a gross overkill amount, like having 700+ wizard towers compared to the usually low (like 70 maybe) that the optimal amount needs?

Answer (score 2):

Your magic recharge time depends on what percent of your magic charge level is left: refilling from 0% to 25% is considerably slower than refilling from 75% to 100%.

The "optimal max magic amount" is the amount that gives you the fastest recharge time when you cast that spell from a full charge.  If your max magic is lower, it takes longer to recharge because the low percentage means you're regaining points slower; if your max is higher, it takes longer because you need to re-gain more points.

Comment: Can you provide some graphs or something that visually explains how or why having a max magic of 100 is less efficient than 43 for casting "Force Hand of Fate" or something? I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it.